# SQL SYNTAX ERROR when creating a table via the terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal, create-table

i'm trying to create a table in mysql on my terminal but this i have this error.

```
mysql> 
 create table reservation (
    id_reservation int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    spectacle_id int,
    restaurant_id int,
    job_dating_id int,
    users_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY(id_reservation),
    FOREIGN KEY(spectacle_id) REFERENCES spectacle(id_spectacle), 
    FOREIGN KEY(restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurant(id_restaurant),
    FOREIGN KEY(job_dating_id) REFERENCES job_dating(id_job_dating),
    FOREIGN KEY(users_id) REFERENCES users(id_users)
  ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: Why formatting/indexing is very important you see errors more easy.. Seams you are are missing `)` at the end.. i would suggest writing SQL queries in a SQL iDE and stop writing those SQL oneliners in a terminal which are hard to debug when errors happen..

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you !! sorry i'm new to developement

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket.